# Can I implement my own filesystem on android?

Tags: java, android, filesystems, google-play, fuse

I have a plan to make a network redirector on android. I’m considering use a FUSE library to make it. The server of network redirector will be amazon S3 or Google Cloud Storage.

I'm very newbie about android. So, before get started, I'd like to check something.

- Is already there a same project?
- Android kernel has the FUSE by default?
- If this project is completed, can it be accepted by android market?
- What FUSE language binding I should use? Can I use java or python to implement user mode filesystem?
- To mount a network volume needs a root privilege? Is the mounting possible without any hacking or rooting?

You can also give me any other advises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fwiw you can't do this with a third party application.  This requires building a custom system image.

Answer (score 0):

FUSE is not enabled in stock Android ROM so you can't use it (i.e. custom ROM would be needed).